# Next.js defaultLocale creates two routes to the same page with and without prefix

Tags: next.js, i18next

According to the [sub path routing documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#sub-path-routing) for Next.js i8n:

> The default locale does not have a prefix.

Yet my issue is that when adding this to my next.config.js:

```
i18n: {
  locales: ['en'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  localeDetection: false,
}
```

All my pages exist under two routes. Both `/en/page` and `/page.` Which implies their documentation is wrong?

Also looking at [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18419) GitHub issue it seems as though people are requesting that the `defaultLocale` not to have a prefix and instead use `default` as a hack to force a prefix, which is the exact opposite of what is happening for me.

Have I missed something critical here and the hack is actually what I need? The only solution I can think of is to add a redirect like this so both pages don't exist together, but I end up in an infinite loop:

```
{
  "source": "/en/:path*",
  "destination": "/:path*",
  "permanent": false
}
```

I'm on these versions:

```
"next": "12.1.5",
"i18next": "^22.4.6",
"next-i18next": "^13.0.2",
"react-i18next": "^12.1.1",
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue but got it working as intended with only one route and a 404 on the other by using the locales format "en-US" instead of just "en" as in the docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing). Hope this helps!